# Print custom schematics logs in angular-cli

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular-schematics

I'm writing custum angular upgrade schematics.

The `SchematicContext` contains a logger object which can be usefull to debug.

```
 context.logger.debug('This logger seems to be usefull!');
```

Running angular-cli, my code is executed but I can't see the logs.

Is there a mean to activate and configure this logger ?

Answer (score 1):

I dont think debug is visible by default level of logging.
Trying changing logging level to info or above.

Comment: Any reason why debug wouldn't be visible? I tried going through the source code and couldn't see any difference with the debug method vs info, warn, etc.

Answer (score 1):

The help says to use `--verbose` but it doesn't work.

```sh
$ ng add --help
options:
  --verbose 
    Display additional details about internal operations during execution.
```

The proper solution is to set the env variable `NG_DEBUG` to `true`.

```sh
# On macOS:
$ NG_DEBUG=true ng add @scope/my-schematic
```

Answer (score 0):

I also can't get .debug to do anything. The other methods work, though: warn, error, info, etc., so at least those are useful. Just be sure to run "yarn build" before running it.